# How to add and change fonts in reveal.js?

Tags: reveal.js

I'm working with `reveal.js` for my next presentation, I want to change the default fonts used for headings.

How can I add and change fonts in `reveal.js`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can do it be modifying the css file of the current theme you are using.

The theme file is located in the folder /css/theme/[yourtheme].css

Once you open the css file for your theme you can see the section for header like below

```
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  margin: 0 0 20px 0;
  color: #eee8d5;
  font-family: "League Gothic", Impact, sans-serif;
  line-height: 0.9em;
  letter-spacing: 0.02em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-shadow: none; }
```

Now you can modify any attribute of you header.

Answer (score 4):

Actually there are lots of fonts. It's just that you have to go around different themes to find appropriate ones for your presentation. I had similar issue with default theme, change it to other theme, find theme inside css/theme

To change theme, change on link tag in index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/default.css" id="theme">
```

change default.css to any other theme files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme/solarized.css" id="theme">
```

Hope it works.

Still if you want to change fonts then, you can change font-family for each tag inside the theme you'll be using by going to the css file of the theme.

Comment: Spot on, check solarized theme.

Answer (score 2):

To add to aatish-sai's answer (thanks!).

A base theme template is here: https://github.com/hakimel/reveal.js/blob/master/css/theme/template/theme.scss.

If I want to change the displayed fonts (say, to Fira Sans) in reveal.js slides generated from a jupyter notebook `foo.ipynb`, it suffices to write the following text

```
.reveal,
.reveal h1,
.reveal h2,
.reveal h3,
.reveal h4,
.reveal h5,
.reveal h6 {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
}
```

to the file `foo.css` in the same directory as the notebook.